# ASP.NET MVC ViewEngine ViewLocationCache.GetViewLocation returns null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewengine

I am following Chris Pietschmann's [solution for theming in ASP.NET MVC](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx).

One thing I have noticed is that the view name is not being retrieved from the ViewLocationCache on subsequent requests. **I am using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RC**

When the following code is executed:

```
this.ViewLocationCache.InsertViewLocation(controllerContext.HttpContext, cacheKey, virtualPath);
```

and I hover over this.ViewLocationCache it just returns {System.Web.Mvc.NullViewLocationCache} - suggesting nothing was added?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ViewLocationCache` only works in release mode by default (setting `<compilation debug="false">` in `web.config`).

To enable `ViewLocationCache` in debug mode:
In a custom view engine that inherits from `WebFormViewEngine`, set the `ViewLocationCache` in your ViewEngine's constructor like so:

```
public MyCustomViewEngine()
{
    ViewLocationCache = new DefaultViewLocationCache();
}
```

You can also override the default cache timespan values if you wish.